# ESP32 Ignores Strapping Pin State: Can't activate 1.8V internal regulator

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

Hardware: ESP32S Dev Kit C2
Software: Arduino IDE 2.0 on Windows 10
MCU: ESP32S
[ESP32 Technical Reference Manual PDF](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf)

Goal: on boot or at runtime, I want to have 1.8V internal regulator activated, so that some of the GPIO work at 1.8V levels.

How: according to technical reference manual, if GPIO12 (MTDI) on power on is HIGH, the voltage regulator will be activated, and a handful of GPIO pins should work at 1.8V. Activating 1.8V at runtime is preferable to fuse burning. Both are doable according to documentation and internet reports.

What I did: I uploaded a blinky sketch, where I do nothing else but toggle GPIO17 every second. That GPIO17 is supposed to be in 1.8V domain. So if I boot it normally, without doing anything with MTDI pin GPIO12 (at 0V on boot), ESP toggles GPIO17 0-3.3V,  which is expected behavior. If I bridge GPIO12 to 3.3V and reset, suddenly the ESP32 starts to output things over serial (my sketch doesn't have any serial! It's literally 5 lines of GPIO code!), and the GPIO doesn't toggle, is stuck at 0.4. Even then, if I don't reset, but disconnect GPIO12 from 3.3V, it stops sending stuff over serial and blinks GPIO17 0-3.3V.
Also, having GPIO12 bridged to 3.3V makes code upload impossible - spews errors. Even tho in the schematic GPIO12 goes straight to the MCU, there is no reason for it to behave like that.

My code:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(17, OUTPUT);
  
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(17, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(17, LOW);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Somewhy, if GPIO12 - MTDI - is at 3.3V on boot, I get infinitely repeating serial message until I disconnect GPIO12 from 3.3V, at which point it stops:

```
rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x33 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46
```

Obviously, it's not supposed to print anything, because my code has no serial.

The questions are:

1. What is going on? Why the heck does the ESP print stuff over serial without my program having anything to do with serial? I guess it's some micropython bootloader, based on my internet search.
2. **Most importantly**, how do I activate 1.8V domain at runtime or on boot (without permanent fuse burn), given instructions from the documentation seem to be misleading? I haven't found even a single successful story on the internet of getting 1.8V there. There are only a few questions here and there, and answers are all vague and non-answers really. There is only talk that it's possible, but there isn't a single working example available.

I'm not experienced with ESP32 (first time using it), but familiar with ARM MCUs, so I would appreciate extra verbosity in answers.

**EDIT: Trying to control voltage regulator from software at runtime**

Spent some more time with the technical reference manual, added this into setup()

```
uint32_t SDIOConfReg = *(uint32_t*)(0x3FF48074);
*(uint32_t*)(0x3FF48074) &= ~(1 << 31); //Software controlled regulator at 1.8V (it's default value, just being explicit for test)
*(uint32_t*)(0x3FF48074) |= (1 << 22); //Enable software regulator control
```

I created variable (and printed it later) to make sure the register works, is accessible and contains sensible values (which it does, so it's definitely the correct register).

Now straight upon power on, the result in COM port is

```
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
invalid header: 0xffffffff
```

I take it, my flash requires 3.3V? I haven't found any way to find out whether flash is 1.8V or 3.3V other than just trying and seeing what happens. Everywhere I look it's like "well, if your flash needs 3.3V, it won't work at 1.8V". Yeah, but how do I know if my flash is 1.8V in the first place. It's not like I can ask it.

Changed software-controlled voltage level of the regulator to 3.3V, works as expected now (blinks at 3.3V). So I believe flash is 3.3V, but I still don't have any way to confirm it documentally, even if I'm certain of it.

```
uint32_t SDIOConfReg = *(uint32_t*)(0x3FF48074);
*(uint32_t*)(0x3FF48074) &= ~(1 << 31); //force 1.8V
*(uint32_t*)(0x3FF48074) |= (1 << 31); //force 3.3V
*(uint32_t*)(0x3FF48074) |= (1 << 22); //regulator software control
```

I believe, what was happening before (when I forced GPIO12 HIGH on boot) is just that I turned on 1.8V for flash on boot, and it probably immediately hardfaulted and/or reset itself, because it couldn't read flash. I would appreciate if someone with more than 5 hours of experience with ESP32 confirmed my theory, it would put my mind at ease.

**EDIT2**

Found some info on flash voltage:
[Espressif SD Pullup Requirements](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v3.2.3/api-reference/peripherals/sd_pullup_requirements.html) contains info on flash voltage. My kit C clearly falls into 3.3V flash voltage. I will need another ESP32.

I guess I have answered my own questions. But hope this post will be useful for someone just as confused as myself.

Comment: The messages are expected; they’re from the first stage bootloader in ROM; as you know you disabled the flash by doing this, so the bootloader couldn’t load instructions from it. Step back a moment, what are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: I need a couple of 1.8V GPIO, so the plan was to use the GPIO, which are powered by VDD_SDIO (which is more than enough current), which comes from that regulator

Comment: That's not going to work, sorry. 1.8V will only be on the flash GPIO pins, which are exclusively for use with the flash. Getting a different board with 1.8V flash isn't going to help you; it will just crash if you try to use those pins at the same time as the flash chip is connected to them. A level shifter is the right solution that problem.

Comment: What do you mean, Flash GPIO only ? There are like 10 GPIOs powered from it according to diagrams. Some of them not connected to Flash (like GPIO17)